# solr saving wrong value of large long

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have a solr schema with a field in long type

```
<field name="source_raw_hash" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

the long type in the schema is the default:

```
<fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

I am saving to the index in solrJ, the value: 3954983690244748504 to this field, but it's being saved as 3954983690244748300

I am having the same with different large values.

Tried change the type to double with is 64 as well, didn't work also.

I am using solr 5.3 and solrj 5.3

Answer (score 1):

You're not indexing longs, you're indexing doubles. Meaning that before the content hits Solr, you're probably storing it as a double somewhere.

When stored as a double, `3954983690244748504` can only be expressed as `3.9549836902447483e+18` (or without the scientific notation, `3954983690244748300`), which matches your second number.

doubles are not exact, they're an approximation - also when it comes to very large numbers.

Comment: Why `fieldType` definition is using `TrieLongField` for long? If this is using double then how to store long values? The document define the limit for long as  `Min Value Allowed: -9223372036854775808` and  `Max Value Allowed: 9223372036854775807`. [TrieLongField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieLongField.html).

Comment: Yes, but your code, somewhere along the way, stores it as a double, and not a long. Solr knows what to do with a long value, but if it's a truncated double value, it will never see the value you think the variable has.

Comment: I added the same value from the Solr Admin UI to long `filed`. But in the results I saw the truncated value. What did I miss? How can I test the long values in Solr Admin UI 5.2.

Comment: No double used anywhere, I Logged the number exactly before adding it to solr and it's correct.

document.addField(TMSegment.FIELD_SOURCE_RAW_HASH, segment.getSourceRawHash());
Logger.debug(segment.getSourceRawHash());